# Trying to set static IPv4 fails

Tags: networking

I've been trying to fix this for some weeks now and I noticed loads of threads here regarding this same error message, although none of them have helped..

When I edit my /etc/network/interfaces to this:

```
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eno1
iface eno1 inet static
address 192.168.1.142
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
```

And I run `sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart` it fails.

Then when I run `sudo systemctl status networking.service` it tells me it *Failed to start Raise network interfaces*.

I want the IPv4 address to be set to 192.168.1.142 and not change after reboots etc.

I've made an reservation for that IP on my router.

What can I do to solve this?

## Update

I saw that the error also says it cannot bring up eno1 because it is not configured *(what)*. Not sure if this has anything to do with it or not, but I thought it might be interesting for you to know!

Comment: Please edit your question to include the result of the terminal command: `ifconfig`

Comment: IIRC, it's pretty picky about tabbing. Make sure it's tabbed correctly